# Whats the font and color of UITableViewCell text?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts

I want to replicate the `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` provided by apple, I just can't figure out the font and size of the text in the cells in the right. Specifically the font and color of numbers below is, 28 1 6843.

[image]

Comment: Just to check, is your question how to SET the font and font sizes for a cell, or do you just need to find out which size is being used here?

Comment: i would like to find out which size is being used here. thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the default font with the label with the 
size = `[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]`;

and the color of the number you are looking for is

`label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:81.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:145.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];`

Comment: Close, but the font size and numbers are off relative to what I found using the method in MJN's answer. I put my details in a comment below his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The area on the right of a `UITableViewCell` is called the `detailTextLabel`.  You can just create a `UITableViewCell` with the style you want and read the `UIFont` and `UIColor` values from it.

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: @"Example"] autorelease];

UIFont* rightFont = cell.detailTextLabel.font;
UIColor* rightColor = cell.detailTextLabel.textColor;
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but there are a couple of caveats. When testing this, I received the following for the `detailText` of `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`: `font-family: "Helvetica"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 0px, color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.22 0.33 0.53 1` Note that the font-size is not reported correctly and the font-weight, though listed as bold, needs to be set to plain to properly match the style. My final settings to replicate the style were: Font = System 17.0 (Helvetica, regular), color (0-255 as set in the color picker) = R 56, G 84, B 135.

Answer (score -1):

**ITableViewCellStyleValue1
A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with left-aligned and black text; on the right side is a label that has smaller blue text and is right-aligned. The Settings application uses cells in this style.**

Comment: whats the RGB of the blue color? or is there any other way to create that color?

Comment: you can find out Rgb Color Value For Particular color.  open xib click on view press cmd+1 then you got list select background get some options the select others then open color window then drag search icon to particular color ....you can know all details.